# Run Keycloak with database contains data

Tags: mysql, keycloak, keycloak-connect

i configured keycloak with mysql database and it worked,
i created a realm, user, role for test and everything was fine,
I stopped keycloak and restarted it with `>standalone.bat`
and i got this error:

```
FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool – 65) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking method [listUnrunChangeSets] on object [liquibase.Liquibase@f0132b4], using arguments [null,(),false]
```

ps: if i delete the database and recreate it and run keycloak it will work but run it with database contains data the error above will appear

Please help me to solve this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution
at the beginning i had the newest version of `mysql-connector-java` it’s `8.0.23`
i replaced it with an old version `8.0.21` and boom it worked for me

ps: of course I modified the file `module.xml`